# How to load a partial view into a container in _Layout.cshtml

Tags: asp.net, view, razor, partial

Hi can someone please tell me how I can load a PartialView into a div container I have prepared located in _Layout.cshtml (that is completely separate from the link itself). I want it loaded into the container on the click of the following action link:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("RenderColorbox", "ContactPartial", new { path = "_ContactPartial" })" class="colorboxLink"><span>ContactUs</span></a>
```

I would like to do this without javascript because I need to create a model in my controller and pass it to the PartialView and I dont think its possible to pass a strongly typed model to a view using javascript.

If I wanted to I could use:

```
$('.colorboxLink').click(function () {
     $('.colorbox_container').load(this.href);
});
```

but as I mentioned this does not give me the chance to create and pass a strongly typed model to the partial view...its important that I can create and pass a model to the view because Im getting a null reference exception when I try something like foreach(var item in Model.ItemList) in the partial view.

Heres what my controller looks like:

```
    public virtual ActionResult RenderColorbox(string path)
    {
        return PartialView(path, null);
    }
```

However, currently, clicking the action link simply renders the PartialView in a new blank page rather than inside the container I have set up.

Thank you all for your help.

EDIT: To load the colorbox I used the following as suggest:

```
    $('.colorboxLink').click(function () {
    $('.colorbox_container').load(this.href, function () {
        var colorboxOptions = {
            inline: true,
            scrolling: false,
            opacity: ".9",
            fixed: true,
            onLoad: function () {
                $('#cboxContent').css({
                    "background": "white"
                });
                $('#cboxLoadedContent').css({
                    "margin-bottom": "28px",
                    "height": "558px"
                });
            }
        }
        $('#contactColorbox').colorbox(colorboxOptions);


    });
```

But still loads without colorbox, but rather as a pop up modal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but as I mentioned this does not give me the chance to create and pass
>   a strongly typed model to the partial view.

It gives you such chance. You are sending an AJAX request to the `RenderColorbox` action on the ContactPartial controller. Inside this action you can prepare and send whatever complex view model you want to the partial:

```
public ActionResult RenderColorbox(string path)
{
    SomeComplexModel model = ...
    return PartialView(path, model);
}
```

Also make sure that you cancel the default action of the link by returning false from the click handler:

```
$(function() {
    $('.colorboxLink').click(function () {
        $('.colorbox_container').load(this.href);
        return false;
    });
});
```

If you don't do this, when you click on the link, your AJAX call has barely any chance to execute before the browser redirects away to the target page.

Comment: Well if I were to use javascript load() like I showed above then I would set onclick="false" on the actionlink, no? because otherwise it just loads the partial view into a blank new page regardless. In that case RenderColorbox() wont get called if onclick="false" right?

Comment: @user1267778, why adding an onclick attribute to your anchor when you already subscribed to it in your javascript? Also the correct would be `onclick="return false;"`, not `onclick="false"`. But don't do this. Don't mix markup and javascript.

Comment: I see. thanks for the help. Since its already on topic can you also help me resolve the issue of the colorbox not loading. In other words, clicking the action link DOES render the view but just as a pop up, not as a colorbox. I have the following script in my partial view that I thought would render the partial view inside a colorbox but it doesnt work: (Look at post for script)

Comment: @user1267778, you should not have any scripts in your partial views. You should call it once the AJAX callback succeeds: `$('.colorbox_container').load(this.href, function() { /** put the code to load the colorbox here **/ })`.

Comment: btw sorry for accidently editing your post I meant to edit my own

Comment: Hi, Im still struggling to have the view load as a colorbox rather than a regular modal. Updated code in original post with recommended syntax but it still loads without a colorbox.  Thanks again.